# Chrome form submit requests sometimes processed as html, or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome

I have a form, with several buttons alongside of it, that are 'controlled' via Javascript.

For instance, the one I'm concerned with does this:

```
    $('.edit_document').submit();
```

So far so good.  I got a few bug reports, from people on Chrome, with Windows, who were having problems with this form.  Turns out that Rails was receiving it as JS, not HTML.

```
Started PUT "/documents/1236" for xxxxxxxxxx at 2012-10-18 08:45:41 +0000
Processing by DocumentsController#update as HTML

Started PUT "/documents/1229" for yyyyyyyyyy at 2012-10-18 08:46:08 +0000
Processing by DocumentsController#update as JS

Started PUT "/documents/1229" for yyyyyyyyyy at 2012-10-18 09:06:25 +0000
Processing by DocumentsController#update as JS

Started PUT "/documents/18" for xxxxxxxxx at 2012-10-18 09:27:15 +0000
Processing by DocumentsController#update as HTML
```

Now, I suppose it's easy enough to add a .js handler, but I'd like to understand better why it's seemingly randomly switching back and forth between the two!

Using: jquery 1.8.2, Rails 3.2.8, Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 on Ubuntu (works as HTML) and Windows (works as JS).

Comment: Can you provide more of your code?

Comment: I can't really add too much more, aside from the fact that the onclick event on the button is caught via javascript, and eventually leads to the `submit()` call.